# Fragment shader to host dependencies

Tags: synchronization, vulkan, memory-barriers

I am writing data in a storage buffer in the fragment shader and trying to read the data on the host directly after. If I am doing the same but using a Compute shader, the barrier works, and I can read the data on the host. But I can get it to work with render passes.

```
// fragment shader
layout (set = 0, binding = 1) writeonly buffer Voxels {
  uvec4 values[10000];
} voxels;
void main() {
    uint cur = atomicAdd(voxels.count, 1);
    voxels.values[cur] = uvec4(1,2,3,4);
}
```

I am trying to add a memory barrier inside my render pass:

```
  VkMemoryBarrier memoryBarrier = {
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER,
    .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT
  };
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, 0, 1, &memoryBarrier, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
```

Render pass(subpass dependency)

```
  VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency = {
      .srcSubpass = 0,
      .dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
      .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
      .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
      .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT,
      .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT,
      .dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_DEVICE_GROUP_BIT 
  };
```

But I getting an error from the validation layer when recording the memory barrier. It says I need subpass self-dependency. But I can´t have any host mask if I have a dependency between subpass 0 and subpass 0?

Error message:

> Barriers cannot be set during subpass 0 of VkRenderPass
>   0x61bb1e000000007b[] with no self-dependency specified. The Vulkan
>   spec states: If vkCmdPipelineBarrier is called within a render pass
>   instance, the render pass must have been created with at least one
>   VkSubpassDependency instance in VkRenderPassCreateInfo::pDependencies
>   that expresses a dependency from the current subpass to itself, and
>   for which srcStageMask contains a subset of the bit values in
>   VkSubpassDependency::srcStageMask, dstStageMask contains a subset of
>   the bit values in VkSubpassDependency::dstStageMask, dependencyFlags
>   is equal to VkSubpassDependency::dependencyFlags, srcAccessMask member
>   of each element of pMemoryBarriers and pImageMemoryBarriers contains a
>   subset of the bit values in VkSubpassDependency::srcAccessMask, and
>   dstAccessMask member of each element of pMemoryBarriers and
>   pImageMemoryBarriers contains a subset of the bit values in
>   VkSubpassDependency::dstAccessMask
>   (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier-pDependencies-02285)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vkCmdPipelineBarrier` inside a Subpass is called Subpass Self-dependency, and as such cannot deal with anything external to subpass, including Host pseudo-pipeline. You need to pre-declare such use of `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` with a `VkSubpassDependency`, where `.srcSubpass == .dstSubpass`. And in such dependency, only Graphics Pipeline stages are allowed.

Your `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` dependency already seems to do all that is needed. So you only need to remove the `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, which is invalid use. I assume you know that you still need to follow up with a Fence.

I am not sure why you have `VK_DEPENDENCY_DEVICE_GROUP_BIT`. Do you actively use device groups?

Comment: VK_DEPENDENCY_DEVICE_GROUP_BIT was just something I added when debugging. Thanks, it´s working now